# Getting file location over an API gateway from a microservice

Tags: laravel, microservices, lumen, api-gateway

I have a microservice that handles document upload and download and an API gateway that aggregates response from different microservices and return them to clients. My question is: I am saving the documents on the server as opposed to saving it on cloud which would have been easy to retrieve via a URL. Who knows how I can make the API gateway return the storage link for easy retrieval by the client without having to use cloud storage?